# Updating the OG attributes after what picture is shown in a Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, facebook-opengraph

I am working on a website that uses the carousel as a slider, a kind of full sized picture carousel. It would be nice to be able to change OG tags as it slides along. Showing the actual picture in the carousel in the sharing and not just one for the whole site.

Is it possible to have Bootstrap Carousel update OpenGraph attributes in the head as it slides? And if so, how? Or is there another way of accomplishing what I want?

The site I'm working on is found at: https://github.com/GauteR/myPortfolio - it's in a pre-alpha state though.

It can be said that the site I'm working on is made in NodeJS, with Express and Jade/Pug as well as Bootstrap 3 and a few other packages, all mentioned within the `package.json` of the GitHub project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue will be solved by basically not updating the OG tags automatically, but by using the identifier to generate the OG attributes for the Facebook spider (and others visiting that site) within Node

- Everyone entering the standard site will get an OG attribute object
  containing site data.
- Everyone entering an album site will get an OG attribute object
  containing album data.
- Everyone entering a specific picture will get an OG attribute object
  containing the picture data.
- Sharing/Re-sharing will generate an url leading to one of the above.